# Posting JSON object to asp.net server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

i am trying to post some json data to to my asp.netserver on my localhost.  The page to receive the code should be the master page, however i tried that and got "Error 403: Forbidden" so i tried my hands on a web service instead and now i am having a  whole load of other issues. My main issue is that i could do this rather simply in PHP but i have no idea how to go about this in ASP.NET.

This is my js file:

```
// Get User Login Credentials
function authenticate() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var user = $('.login-box form #txtLoginUsername').val().trim();
        var pass = $('.login-box form #txtLoginPass').val().trim();

        // alert(user + " : " + pass);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "postback.asmx/Verify",
            data: {
                user: user,
                pass: pass
            },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function() {
                if (response)
                {
                    alert('Works');
                }
                else {
                    $(".ui-widget").slideDown(1000, function () {});
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Now i call this function on a button click event,  i do not add my server code because it comprises of several lines of code i picked up from the net and tried to mash up to get my page to work, which it didn't.  I would like to know a simple appropriate method of getting JSON objects from a post and return a value/array from my server.

Please i do not wish to use any asp.net server controls for certain reasons i am unable to disclose, but i have been restricted from using such controls.

Comment: Rolling your own security is a notoriously bad idea.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to be getting something back from success like success: function(data){}

Comment: Yeah i am, but i will implement that later, i just want to focus on getting the postback to work for now.

Comment: Can you make sure IIS has read/write permissions to the service you are trying to call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can´t put your WebMethod in an masterPage. Ajax is client side and you are getting the same error if you tried to acess site.master in your browser.

"Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.master' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly. "

You can implement your WebMethod in other file .aspx and call by ajax.

I wrote an little example.

cs

```
[WebMethod(enableSession: true)]
public static void Verify(string user, String pass)
{

    throw new Exception("I´m here");

}
```

js

```
function authenticate() {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var user = $('#txtLoginUsername').val().trim();
                var pass = $('#txtLoginPass').val().trim();

                // alert(user + " : " + pass);
                var data = {};
                data.user = user;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "default.aspx/Verify",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        user: user,
                        pass: pass
                    }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function () {
                        if (response) {
                            alert('Works');
                        }
                        else {
                            $(".ui-widget").slideDown(1000, function () { });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

pay attention how Json is passing to data

```
data: JSON.stringify({
                            user: user,
                            pass: pass
                        }),
```

To call webservice, try pass json this way.

When you call web service there are same error message in browser´s console?

I think this is will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.stringify() method as explained in follow
var jsonData=your Jason data;
Data:JSON.stringify(jsonData)

courtsey:
http://www.dotnetlines.com/forum/tabid/86/forumid/6/postid/72/scope/posts/Default.aspx#72

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
[WebMethod]
public string Verify(string user,string pass)
{
  //DataTable dt = YourMethod_ReturningDataTable(); 
  //retrun dt.toJson();
  //But in your case 
  bool IsAllowedtoLogin = true;
  return IsAllowedtoLogin.toJson(); 
}
```

For this (toJson) method you have create a static class.This will convert even datatable to json format.

```
public static string toJson(this DataTable dataTable)
{

    string[] StrDc = new string[dataTable.Columns.Count];

    string HeadStr = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {

        StrDc[i] = dataTable.Columns[i].Caption;
        HeadStr += "\"" + StrDc[i] + "\" : \"" + StrDc[i] + i.ToString() + "¾" + "\",";

    }

    HeadStr = HeadStr.Substring(0, HeadStr.Length - 1);
    StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

    Sb.Append("{\"" + dataTable.TableName + "\" : [");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        string TempStr = HeadStr;

        Sb.Append("{");
        for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
        {

            TempStr = TempStr.Replace(dataTable.Columns[j] + j.ToString() + "¾", dataTable.Rows[i][j].ToString());

        }
        Sb.Append(TempStr + "},");

    }
    Sb = new StringBuilder(Sb.ToString().Substring(0, Sb.ToString().Length - 1));

    Sb.Append("]}");
    return Sb.ToString();

}
```

Note that data parameters are case sensitive. i.e user , pass .

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "default.aspx/Verify",
                data: "{'user':'"+yourvariable+"','pass':'"+yourvariable+"'}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    data = JSON && JSON.parse(data.d) || $.parseJSON(data.d); 
                    if (data == "true") {
                        alert('Works');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".ui-widget").slideDown(1000, function () { });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Your method didn't work for me, i got an error from the server, something to do with the function but your code on the client side did help me out however. :)